# Aggregation result of two values within the same document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB 3.6 database and I have several documents in one collection.
All documents have the same properties like:

```
{"type": "stuff", "price1": 2, "price2": 5, "total_cost": }
```

I would like to have the sum of `price1` and `price2` as value for `total_cost`, is it possible to do that?
And if I update `price1` or `price2`, it will update automatically `total_cost`.

```
{"type": "stuff", "price1": 2, "price2": 5, "total_cost": 7 }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you want is a trigger. I don't believe mongodb has trigger kind of thing. You should implement your logic in the query itself.

Comment: Do you want a aggregate that return `type`, `price1`, `price2` and `total_cost`? If so, Do you want to calculate `total_cost` on the fly or update your collection before with the value `total_cost` calculated?

Answer (score 0):

You can search about the `$out` stage of the aggregation pipeline, but I think it will create a new collection in your database. To do your job, you need to compute your total in your code and `$set` after the result in your document.